# How to create global object accessible to src/ code as well as lib/ libraries?

Tags: c++, arduino, platformio

I'm trying to get started with PlatformIO and have hit a wall with include priorities and/or variable scopes.

My code consists of a `src/main.cpp` program as well as several private libraries which reside in the `lib/<libname>/*.cpp/h` location.

I want to have a global object of an external class ([Syslog](https://platformio.org/lib/show/1506/Syslog)) which is accessible to both my main program as well as any private libraries I've added.

I've currently tried 2 approaches, which both refuse to compile:

---

Create the object in main.cpp with the extern keyword, initialize the object in `setup()` like so:

src/main.cpp:

```
#include <Syslog.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
WiFiUDP SyslogUDP;
extern Syslog syslog;
void setup()
{
   syslog = Syslog(SyslogUDP, "255.255.255.255", 514, "FlyballETS", "FlyballETSApp", LOG_INFO, SYSLOG_PROTO_BSD);
}
```

lib/GPSHandler/GPSHandler.cpp:

```
void GPSHandlerClass::init(HardwareSerial * SerialPort)
{
   syslog.logf_P("GPS Class initialized!");
}
```

This results in compiler errors like:

```
lib\GPSHandler\GPSHandler.cpp:22:4: error: 'syslog' was not declared in this scope
```

---

The 2nd approach I tried (this works in Arduino IDE), was creating a small `SyslogHelper.h` file, which created the `extern Syslog syslog;` object, and then include this helper file in all my private libs, like so:

src/main.cpp:

```
#include "SyslogHelper.h"
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
WiFiUDP SyslogUDP;

void setup()
{
   syslog = Syslog(SyslogUDP, "255.255.255.255", 514, "FlyballETS", "FlyballETSApp", LOG_INFO, SYSLOG_PROTO_BSD);
}
```

src/SyslogHelper.h:

```
#include <Syslog.h>
extern Syslog syslog;
```

lib/GPSHandler/GPSHandler.cpp:

```
#include "SyslogHelper.h"
void GPSHandlerClass::init(HardwareSerial * SerialPort)
{
   syslog.logf_P("GPS Class initialized!");
}
```

When I try to compile this in PlatformIO, it fails because at the time it tries to compile SyslogHelper.h, it doesn't seem to be aware of the location of the `<Syslog.h>` file:

```
In file included from lib\GPSHandler\GPSHandler.cpp:7:0:
src/SyslogHelper.h:4:20: fatal error: Syslog.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

While I realize you say you want a global object shared between a library and your private libraries, I am going to assert that is not the best design pattern as it is brittle and error-prone (as you are experiencing). A better approach is to pass the `SysLog` object you create in your main code as an argument to any method that needs it. The reason this is better is because you are explicitly declaring then what methods can and should use the `Syslog` object.

However, if you really must have a global variable, the second best pattern is to use a accessor class that looks something like this:

**SysLogHelper.h**

```
#ifndef __SysLogHelper_h__
#define __SysLogHelper_h__

#include <Syslog.h>

class SysLogHelper {
private:
    Syslog *_instance;

public:
    static Syslog& instance( void );

    Syslog();
    virtual ~Syslog()
}
#endif // __SysLogHelper_h__
```

**SysLogHelper.cpp**

```
#include "SysLogHelper.h"

SysLogHelper gSysLogHelper();

Syslog& SysLogHelper::instance( void ) {
    return gSysLogHelper._instance;
}

SysLogHelper::SysLogHelper() {
    _instance = Syslog(SyslogUDP, "255.255.255.255", 514, "FlyballETS", "FlyballETSApp", LOG_INFO, SYSLOG_PROTO_BSD);
}

SysLogHelper::~SysLogHelper() {
    delete _instance;
}
```

Then anywhere in your code you want to use the `SysLog` object, simply include the `SysLogHelper.h` header, and use your `SysLog` instance by calling the static method, something like this:

```
#include "SyslogHelper.h"
void GPSHandlerClass::init(HardwareSerial * SerialPort)
{
   SyslogHelper::instance().logf_P("GPS Class initialized!");
}
```

Feel free to rename things to your preference. Also, with some creativity, you can have more than one `SysLog` object in this accessor class, each configured differently.